# SharePoint 2010 SEO meta description

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, seo

When I try to amend my page layouts to accept a new SEO meta description site column (as per this post, for example: http://www.bentedder.com/sharepoint-seo-generate-meta-descriptions-for-your-public-facing-sharepoint-pages/comment-page-1/#comment-5581), my pages based on the page layout lock up.

Can't scroll on the page and when I click to Edit the page (from the ribbon), I just get an indefinite "Loading..." message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I created a new ContentPlaceHolder in my custom master page and I reference this new placeholder in asp:Content tags in my page layouts.

Here, with the pagelayout modification, is where the scrollbar disappears and the ribbon becomes unusable.

My hunch is that the placement of my asp:Content tags in the pagelayouts is making them malformed and causing the errors. I have tried placing the code before/after (even within) PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead - to no avail.

I don't see anything of value in the logs. Any ideas as to what I can do to troubleshoot/debug?